# Installing EAR file through WebSphere 8. 5 wsadmin

Tags: java, websphere, business-objects

I installed SAP BusinessObjects using wsadmin successfully but can't figure out how to start the application:

```
wsadmin>$AdminApp install "C:/websphere-ears/BOE.ear"

ADMA5016I: Installation of BOE started.
ADMA5058I: Application and module versions are validated with versions of deployment targets.
ADMA5005I: The application BOE is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5005I: The application BOE is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5081I: The bootstrap address for client module is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5053I: The library references for the installed optional package are created.
ADMA5005I: The application BOE is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5001I: The application binaries are saved in C:\software\websphere app server\profiles\AppSrv03\wstemp\Script1464d745f98\workspace\cells\U6017576-TPL-A
Node01Cell\applications\BOE.ear\BOE.ear
ADMA5005I: The application BOE is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
SECJ0400I: Successfully updated the application BOE with the appContextIDForSecurity information.
ADMA5005I: The application BOE is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5005I: The application BOE is configured in the WebSphere Application Server repository.
ADMA5113I: Activation plan created successfully.
ADMA5011I: The cleanup of the temp directory for application BOE is complete.
ADMA5013I: Application BOE installed successfully.
```

Then I try to start the application but it's reported to not be installed immediately proceeding a successful install:

```
wsadmin>set appManager [$AdminControl queryNames type=ApplicationManager,*]
WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=U6017576-           TPL-ANode01,version=8.5.0.0,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=Applicat
ionManager,cell=U6017576-TPL-ANode01Cell,spec=1.0

wsadmin>$AdminControl invoke $appManager startApplication BOE
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "$AdminControl invoke $appManager startApplication BOE"; exception information:
javax.management.MBeanException
com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationWarning: Application BOE not installed
```

Any ideas on why its not recognizing the application?

Comment: do you run a save command? maybe that's why it's failing after the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you install an application, you have to do the following things:

1. Save the configuration. Remember that `wsadmin` creates a copy of the WebSphere configuration for you to play with; when you'd like your changes (such as a new application installed) effective, you must save the configuration so it's merged with WebSphere's master repository.
2. If you're running in a Network Deployment topology, you must also synchronize the master configuration across all nodes. Usually this is done automatically on a predefined interval, but there are end cases in which you might attempt to start a newly-installed application before the new configuration had the chance to propagate to all environments. So, it's a good practice to synchronize the node after a deployment operation. (This step is irrelevant if you're running a Single Server topology)